# How to Create new scope under super scope in windows using command?

Tags: windows, dhcp, dhcp-server

AM trying to create new scope under my exissting superscope. like below
+hostname
++IPV4
+++Superscopename
++++newscopes

using below command

```
netsh dhcp server add scope <new_scope> <subnet> <comment>.
```

but it is not creating under super scope.creating like below
+hostname
++IPV4
+++Superscopename
+++newscopes

Could any one suggest me , am i doing wrong ? or is there any other way to create scope ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to Set your Superscope to active, then your creating scope commands will automatically create scopes efficiently under the active Superscope.

> set superscope MySuperScope 1 > (this sets the superscope to use for
>   the rest of your DHCP creating session)

Then create IPs/Scopes you want to add by using the same command

> netsh dhcp server add scope